# How to mark an entire domain as 410 Gone in nginx?

Tags: nginx

As part of taking a site out of commission, I wanted to configure nginx to send a 410 Gone for all URLs. The most simple configuration was like this:

```
server {
  listen 127.0.0.1:8080;
  server_name example.ch www.example.ch;

  root /srv/www/sites/example.ch/public;

  return 410;
}
```

This seems like it should work, but for some reason, when I go to the root of the domain, I instead get a 404 Not Found, and if I go to any other URL, I get a 500 Internal Server Error with this message in the nginx error log:

> rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /adsf HTTP/1.1", host: "example.ch:8080"

This makes very little sense to me. I've also tried replacing the `return 410` with `error_page 404 =410 410.html;`, or even wrapping the `return 410` in a `location / {}` block, but the result is exactly the same.

Can anyone help me figure out what's going on?

Comment: Why it listens to `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: What other server blocks are there and what `listen` directive do they have?

Comment: There's a bunch of other server blocks for other domain names, as well as a `listen 8080 default_server;` for non-matched domains. The reason it listens on `127.0.0.1` is that I have Varnish in front of it, which takes port 80.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the problem was I was mixing `listen 127.0.0.1:8080;` and `listen 8080;` across my server blocks, which was the problem in this case.

So this configuration works great:

```
server {
  listen 8080; # Because I have Varnish in front of nginx.
  server_name example.ch www.example.ch;

  root /srv/www/sites/example.ch/public;

  return 410;
}
```